# Converting an ElementHandle to a DOM element using puppeteer?

Tags: dom, puppeteer, dom-element

This is how I currently get each `DOM` property from an `ElementHandle` :

```
 let section: ElementHandle = await page.waitForSelector(".selector-list li");
 let tagName = await section.$eval('a', (e) => e.tagName);
```

But here it's `tagName`. What if I'd like want to inspect further properties ?

I don't want to write `$eval` for each property.

**Question:**

How can I convert  `ElementHandle` to a Dom object , so I'd be able 
to browse all properties  ?
   I want to get `A` as a Dom object.

Comment: I'm sorry off topic, the let selection: syntax is confusing to me as I've not seen it before.  Can someone point to what type of LET this is?  I only know LET as a variable definition and the : is new to me.

Comment: @Hellonearthis it's typescript. the `:` is not mandatory , but it lets you have a seatbelt while programming ( not runtime). so this will cause error in compilation time : `let a:string=3`

Comment: Thanks @Eris I see it's the way TS does type safety.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The better way would be to execute the code on the page via [page.evaluate](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.9.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) and return the results. That way you can return an array with values:

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".selector-list li");
    // do something with elements, like mapping elements to an attribute:
    return Array.from(elements).map(element => element.tagName);
});
```

`result` will then be an array with the attribute values of `tagName` of each element.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`ElementHandle.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleevaluatepagefunction-args):

```js
const elementHandle = await page.waitForSelector('.selector-list li')

elementHandle.evaluate((domElement) => {
    domElement.tagName  
    // etc ...
})
```

---

Typescript:

```js
const elementHandle: ElementHandle = await page.waitForSelector('.selector-list li')

elementHandle.evaluate((domElement) => {
    domElement.tagName  
    // etc ...
})
```

Comment: You will need to also add a generic type to the `ElementHandle` or else the access to `domElement.tagName` will cause a type error, since it will only have access to attributes of the TypeScript `Element` interface. For example, I had to use `elementHandle.evaluate()` to access the `value` attribute of an `<input>` element. To get around the type error, I did `const elementHandle: ElementHandle<HTMLInputElement> = ...`, which is legal because `HTMLInputElement` is a descendent of `Element`.